# Update a tbody's html with javascript (no lib): possible?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I want to update the contents of a TBODY (not the entire TABLE, because there's much more semi-meta data (LOL) in that). I get >= 0 TR's from the server (XHR) and I want to plump those in the existing table. The fresh TR's must overwrite the existing TBODY contents.

I've made a very simple, static [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/hZUkW/) that works in Chrome and probably all the rest, except for IE (I only use Chrome and test in IE8).

In Chrome, the very first attempt works: plump the TR's in the TBODY. No problem!
In IE it doesn't... I've included a not working example of what I had in mind to get it working.

I'm sure this problem isn't new: **how would I insert a string with TR's in an existing TBODY?**

PS. jQuery doesn't have a problem with this!? It's used here on SO. jQuery does something to the HTML and then inserts it as HTML nodes..? Or something? I can't read that crazy lib. It happens [in this file](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js) (look for `"html: function("`. That's where the magic starts.

Anybody have a function or idea for this to work **without JS library**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/innerhtml-gotchas) is a good resource about the problems of `innerHTML` and IE.

The bottom line is that on `tbody` the `innerHTML` property is readonly.

Here is a solution presented in one of the comments:

```
var innerHTML = "<tr><td>Hello world!</td></tr>";
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.innerHTML = "<table>" + innerHTML + "</table>";
// Get the tr from the table in the div
var trElem = div.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
```

Regarding the jQuery part of the question:

```
//inside the html() function:
// If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
} catch(e) {
  this.empty().append( value );
}

//inside the empty() function (basically removes all child nodes of the td):
while ( elem.firstChild ) {
  elem.removeChild( elem.firstChild );
}

//append calls domManip applying this to all table rows:
if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
  this.appendChild( elem );
}

//domManip as far as I can tell creates a fragment if possible and calls the three lines above with this=each row in turn, elem=the tbody(created if missing)
```

Comment: Huh... I try dumping the TR's in a DIV. Doesn't work. Why the hell did I not think of dumping them in a TABLE?? LOL I'm gonna try this! **edit** But what does jQuery do? jQuery doesn't know what it's appending to what... I know I have a TBODY and TR's.

Comment: Perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/hZUkW/ Thanks a whole lot! (Still curious about how jQ does it though...)

Comment: Whats up with your goofy quotes?

Comment: Sorry about the quotes :) copy paste from the comment I mentioned

Comment: How are the fragments created in/by `domManip`? You can only insert (multiple!) TR's in a TBODY or TABLE (and not even directly!)... The `value` in `.append(value)` contains multiple TR's, so is multiple nodes (but a string). How does that string become actual node objects to append?? I've seen the jQ code. I still don't get it =)

Comment: Tracing in `domManip` : `results = jQuery.buildFragment( args, this, scripts );`, in `buildFragment`: `jQuery.clean( args, doc, fragment, scripts );`, in `clean` it creates a `div`, wraps the rows in `<table><tbody>` and inserts them in the div using innerHTML. Than it removes the wrapping and returns the created elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain JavaScript, you can set the [`innerHTML`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/apis-in-html-documents.html#dom-innerhtml) property of the relevant element. The text that you set can contain a mix of HTML and text. It will be parsed and added to the DOM.

Comment: Not closely enough, my mistake.